# Adding sting to end of URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i want a simple scritp to add string **/output/filename.zip?download=zip** to end of submited urls

for example we have an input box and user submitted 3 urls (or more):

```
test.com/123
test.com/321
test.com/444
```

and when the user clicked on submit button he/she recieved 3 linkable urls:

```
test.com/123/output/filename.zip?download=zip
test.com/321/output/filename.zip?download=zip
test.com/444/output/filename.zip?download=zip
```

do u know any script or simple codes?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the information you provided, it is difficult to provide an exact answer.

Just a general way to do it would be something like this.

```
  const files = ['test.com/123', 'test.com/321', 'test.com/444'];
  for ( let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    files[i] = files[i] + '/output/filename.zip?download=zip';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the values from different input fields all you need to do is use the form method to access them like this.

```
if($_POST){
  echo $_POST["link1"] .= '/output/filename.zip?download=zip';
  echo $_POST["link2"] .= '/output/filename.zip?download=zip';
}

<form action="#" method="post">
    <label>Link 1:</label>
    <input type="text"name="link1"><br><br>
    <label>Link 2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="link2"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

otherwise if you are getting all the values from one input field. You should ask users to use a seperator for between links like `,` that way you can use `explode` function to get each value as an array.